# How do i use Webform API to submit my Custom Module form?

Tags: forms

OK kinda noob-ish question but im unfamiliar with the programing side of Drupal... Im currently building a Form from scratch in drupal 7 (custom module since im using Form_Panel to arrange my form fields) and i would like to implement the webform API into my code as the submit handler.(This way i can hopefully use webform UI to deal with submissions and viewing results at least) Currently i have all the form fields and a submit button but not much else...

```
function my_module_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['my_module/form'] = array(
'title' => t('Subscription'),
'page callback' => 'my_module_form',
'access arguments' => array('access content'),
'description' => t('Subscription'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
return $items;
//some random fields from form API after
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Submit button
$form['submit'] = array( 
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => 'Submit',
 '#submit' => array('my_module_my_form_submit'),
);
return $form;
}
function my_module_my_form_submit($edit,$form, $form_state) {
drupal_set_message('Submission recieved.');
}
```

And thats it.It shows perfectly on site and submit refreshes the page.. What i need to know is which function and methods should i use to get webform or drupal period to save my values(create a db table first?) and display them at the necessary time through whatever links on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) in your `module.install` file to make a database table to store your values. A small stupid logging schema I wrote is as follows:

```
function idprocessing_schema() {
  $schema['idprocessing_log'] = array(
    'description' => 'webextract process logging',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'id of entry',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'created' => array(
        'description' => 'The Unix timestamp when the entry was made.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'msg' => array(
        'description' => 'whats going on in the processing',
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'medium',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'num_students' => array(
        'description' => 'number of students from xpath query',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

You then insert into the table as needed with say `db_insert()` a Database API function of drupal.

```
  db_insert('idprocessing_log')
    ->fields(array(
      'msg' => $msg,
      'num_students' => $cnt,
      'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->execute();
```

You would want to insert `$form_state['values']` by the way in your `my_module_my_form_submit` function.

Comment: ok thanks, why do i need $form_state['values'](curiosity purposes)? and do i include this in the .install or .inc file?

Comment: the form submission values are sent to your submission function in the `$form_state` array, specifcally the `"values"` key. ..... so you wont be inserting anything without that :P. the `hook_schema()` goes in `yourmodule.install` your form submission function goes in your `yourmodule.module` file.